# CentOS 6 Mono and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, mono

EDIT: Added some extra logs at the end

I'm trying to make Mono 3.0 work on CentOS 6 with Apache. I have compiled Mono, mod_mono and the XPS server from the source. But now I'm getting errors because it doesn't seem to be pointing to the right place.

I want to store my files under /home/mvcgui/wwwroot/. I have put the 'apache' user in the mvcgui group. I've created a VHOST pointing there, like so:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@tralala.com
        DocumentRoot /home/mvcgui/wwwroot
#       ServerName mvcgui
        ErrorLog /home/mvcgui/logs/error.log
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>
        MonoServerPath mvc4 "/opt/mono/bin/mod-mono-server4"
        # Dev mode
        MonoDebug mvc4 true
        MonoSetEnv mvc4 MONO_IOMAP=all;PATH=/opt/mono/bin;LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mono/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;

        MonoApplications mvc4 "/:/home/mvcgui/wwwroot"
        <Location />
        Allow from all
        Order allow,deny
        MonoSetServerAlias mvc4
        SetHandler mono
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I make a request to localhost I get this error in the VHOST logs:

```
Fri Mar 22 15:52:35 2013] [error] [client ::1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

I believe however that the rights are correct?

```
[root@localhost mvcgui]# ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 mvcgui mvcgui 4096 Mar 22 11:41 logs
drwxrwxr-x 7 mvcgui mvcgui 4096 Mar 22 11:14 wwwroot

[root@localhost wwwroot]# ls -l
total 80
drwxr-xr-x 2 mvcgui mvcgui  4096 Mar 22 11:13 bin
drwxr-xr-x 5 mvcgui mvcgui  4096 Mar 22 11:13 Content
-rw-r--r-- 1 mvcgui mvcgui 32038 Mar 22 11:13 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 mvcgui mvcgui  3790 Mar 22 11:13 Foundation_readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mvcgui mvcgui    97 Mar 22 11:13 Global.asax
-rw-r--r-- 1 mvcgui mvcgui   246 Mar 22 11:13 humans.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 mvcgui mvcgui  4096 Mar 22 11:14 Images
-rw-r--r-- 1 mvcgui mvcgui  3103 Mar 22 11:13 packages.config
-rw-r--r-- 1 mvcgui mvcgui   110 Mar 22 11:13 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x 3 mvcgui mvcgui  4096 Mar 22 11:14 Scripts
drwxr-xr-x 8 mvcgui mvcgui  4096 Mar 22 11:14 Views
-rw-r--r-- 1 mvcgui mvcgui  4543 Mar 22 11:13 Web.config
[root@localhost wwwroot]#
```

Note that SELinux and iptables are disabled.

Where could I look to get more troubleshoot info?

EDIT: Under /etc/httpd/logs/error_log I have noticed a more detailed error that shows up only when I start the service:

```
[Mon Mar 25 09:48:37 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
mod-mono-server received a shutdown message
[Mon Mar 25 09:48:38 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Mar 25 09:48:38 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Mar 25 09:48:38 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Mar 25 09:48:38 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_mono/2.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_global
Root directory: /
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_global
Root directory: /
Error: Address already in use
mod-mono-server4
Exception caught during reading the configuration file:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler.Create'.
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.get_AppSettings () [0x00001] in /home/arnaud/Downloads/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/main.cs:208
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x0002a] in /home/arnaud/Downloads/xsp-2.10.2/src/Mono.WebServer.Apache/main.cs:63
Error: Directory "/home/mvcgui/wwwroot/" not found.
[root@localhost conf.d]#
```

Comment: The error concerning the Method not found was fixed by pointing the lib path from /opt/mono/lib/mono/4.0/mod-mono-server4.exe to /opt/mono/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe. Mod-mono-server4.exe also had to be moved to the 4.5 lib directory. However the problem with the directory not being found is still happening and I have no idea why. Does mod-mono-server run as a different user than apache?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on openSuse 13.1 after upgrading to Mono 3.2 and apache 2.4
The problem for me was actually a simple permission problem, my htdocs directory was not accessible by the mod-mono-server process.

I am using the *User* and *Group* directives of apache to set the ownership of the apache process. Previously, these settings where inherited by mod-mono-server, but this doesn't work in apache-2.4 due to a [bug in mod_mono](https://github.com/mono/mod_mono/pull/3). You can check the user and group id mod-mono-server is running under with:

```
ps ax -o pid,user,group,ruser,rgroup,args|grep mono
```